# Counting entries of a unique entry of another field and concatenate the result with the unique field in a new column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, count, sequence, incremental-load

I want to create a query that will search the table and find the following:

If a `POL_N` entry has `ENDO_N` entries then the `COUNT ENDO_N` field will start counting the `ENDO_N` entries and will get the assigned name as shown below.

For example `POL002` has two `ENDO_N` entries, hence the `COUNT ENDO_N` will be `POL002-1` and `POL002-2`.

Do you have any suggestions?

[image: SAMPLE RESULT]

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: I'm still a little confused by your explanation. Can you please edit the question, restating the rules in a different way, perhaps explaining line-by-line what's happening.

Comment: If ENDO_N exists for POL_N then the COUNT ENDO_N values will be based on the POL_N +' ' + increment value based on how many ENDO_N are assigned to unique POL_N. I don't know if this helped you much

Answer (score 1):

I recreated the table specified with the next T-SQL code:

```
create table StackOverflowTest(POL_N nvarchar(100),ENDO_N nvarchar(100));
insert into StackOverflowTest(POL_N,ENDO_N)
values('POL001','0'),
      ('POL002','0'),
      ('POL002','ENDO001'),
      ('POL002','ENDO002'),
      ('POL003','ENDO003'),
      ('POL003','ENDO004');
```

T-SQL for getting the column specified. I would be wary of doing this on large datasets though, this is the unoptimized first draft:

```
  select POL_N,
         ENDO_N,
         case when ENDO_N = cast(0 as nvarchar(2)) 
         then cast(0 as nvarchar(2)) 
         else  POL_N +'-'+ cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY POL_N ORDER BY ENDO_N desc) as nvarchar(100)) 
         end as COUNT_ENDO_N
    from StackOverflowTest
    order by POL_N, COUNT_ENDO_N;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have tried this and it works but it assigns as a value to COUNT ENDO_N the POL_N+1. The new value of COUNT ENDO_N should be POL_N + '_'+ n where n will be a variable that will increment +1 if ENDO_N exists